# How to check for a specific value in a specific column of a CSV file (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, csv

My CSV file looks like this, but with some more content:

```
id   name      username    password    city
1    Random    Random123   random123   Berlin
2    Madeup    Name123     madeup123   London
```

Using Powershell, I need to check the "city" column and find all the users who live in "Berlin". Then, I need to create a ".txt" file with their usernames in it.

I know it's such a basic exercise, but I'm just getting started with PowerShell and, although I tried many possible solutions found in Stack Overflow, none of them have worked for me.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may start with reading the help topics for [Import-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.2) and [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2) and [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.2). You should read the help topics for the cmdlets completely including the examples to learn how to use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending all day wondering why all these answers from the internet worked on other CSVs but not in mine, I found out that setting the delimiter was the solution for my problem.

Earlier, I forgot to mention that my CSV was delimited by ';' , so it actually looks like this:

```
id;name;username;password;city
1;Random;Random123;random123;Berlin
2;Madeup;Name123;madeup123;London
```

In the end, I just used [Walter Mitty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19937/walter-mitty)'s answer (thank you, by the way!), with these added modifications, and it worked out.

In case any student out there is bumping against the same problem as me, this was my solution:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\yourUser\Desktop\your.csv -Delimiter ';' -Encoding Default | Where {$_.city -eq "Berlin"}
```

After this, you just have to create a new file with the command "New-Item":

```
New-Item C:\Users\yourUser\Desktop\your.txt
```

And set its content with "Set-Content":

```
Set-Content C:\Users\yourUser\Desktop\your.txt $csv.username
```

Hope this helps somebody in the future. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $mylist = Import-Csv myfile.csv -Delimiter ';'| Where-Object City -eq 'Berlin'
```

$mylist will contain an array of PSCustomObjects.  The properties will be the fields of your csv.  For further help on Where-Object  see the [online help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2).

**Edit** fixed up to include the delimiter semicolon.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering! I tried this, but, unfortunately, $mylist doesn't grab anything, so my .txt file remains unedited and empty. Any idea why this might be happening? In fact, it's not grabbing anything, even when I try to take other fields like "password".

Comment: Maybe 'Berlin' has to be padded out with blanks so as to make it match the length of the field.

Comment: I forgot to put in the delimiter qualifier.  Fixed in the answer.